# How do i get the itemsourcechanged event? Listbox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can i get the itemsourcechangedevent in listbox?

For eg. the itemsource changes from null to ListA then to ListB

I know there is no such event. But is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Under what condition is the data source of your ListBox changing? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A commonly used (answered) approach is use the `PropertyChangedTrigger` from the Blend SDK.  However I don't like recommending the use of other SDKs unless there is a clear indication the SDK is already in use.

I'll assume for the moment that its in code-behind that you want listen for a "ItemsSourceChanged" event.  A technique you can use is to create a `DependencyProperty` in your `UserControl` and bind it to the ItemsSource of the control you want to listen to.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceWatcherProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
       "ItemsSourceWatcher",
       typeof(object),
       typeof(YourPageClass),
       new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged));

private static void OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    YourPageClass source = d As YourPageClass;
    if (source != null)
        source.OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged();  
}

private void OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged()
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Now given that your `ListBox` has a name "myListBox" you can set up watching with:-

```
Binding b = new Binding("ItemsSource") { Source = myListBox };
SetBinding(ItemsSourceWatcherProperty, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ItemsSourceChanged` event in `Silverlight`.

But, there is a workaround. Use `RegisterForNotification()` method mentioned in [this article](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/12/silverlight-listening-to-dependency.html) to register a property value change callback for `ListBox`'s  *ItemsSource* property.

Comment: I can't begin to describe how many ways that approach is just wrong. Its kind of the right approach (the use dependency property callback) but the implementation is just terrible.